# apt-get how to know what to install

Tags: apt

If I only know what feature I want to add to my server/desktop, for example a mail server, how on earth, can I tell what packages should I get via apt-get?

Comment: You could, for example, search for "[Ubuntu mail server](https://www.google.ie/search?hl=en&q=ubuntu+mail+server)", which would tell you that the `postfix` package would give you a mail server. It would be a good idea to further research and find the exact program / features you need, and then find a program which offers those features. (Not all mail servers are the same)

Comment: This probably comes under the use case of Debian Package Tags. See `debtags` For a specific example, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272079/4671.

Comment: Try: `apt search "mail server"` or `apt search database GUI`. It searches the package names & descriptions.

Answer (score 7):

You can always look it up, which is just what I do.

Using your example of wanting to install an email server, I would open Google and search

```
set up email server ubuntu
```

With that search, the first result is this DigitalOcean article, titled "[How To Install and Setup Postfix on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04)." ([Also exists for 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04)) Now I know that the email server on Ubuntu is most likely called Postfix, and I also have a guide on setting it up.

Now, maybe I don't like DigitalOcean for whatever reason, or maybe I'd just prefer a StackExchange Q&A, because those are easier to read for me. With that in mind, I'd search

```
set up email server ubuntu
```

And voila: [How do I set up an email server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54960/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-server)

That contains a very detailed answer on setting up a mail server on Ubuntu, using the `mail-server` package. One result below that question is this one: [simple method to install a mail server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227209/simple-method-to-install-a-mail-server)

It provides yet another method for setting up a mail server.

---

What you really, really, *really* need to do when using Ubuntu (well, anything really) is *look it up*. I could say there's no index that lists all the packages for different mail servers, but there is; it's called The Internet. Use this index to your advantage. Package names can be weird, which is why using a search engine can be very beneficial.

If it turns out you can't find what you're looking for, ask here, as you have just done. Chances are, it already has an answer and will be closed as a duplicate (I'm seeing more and more of those lately, and this question is very likely one as well), but there's nothing wrong with that, especially if you get your answer. In fact, duplicates help others as well, as your question might show up to different search terms than the question it is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 5):

You can just try `apt-cache search 'mail server'`. It should list packages related to this search and in this state, you should be able to select which one you need.

`apt-cache search 'mail server'` results in my system these

```
→ apt-cache search 'mail server'
ktnef - Viewer for mail attachments using TNEF format
libkf5ksieveui5 - Sieve, the mail filtering language, GUI library
libksieveui5 - Sieve, the mail filtering language, GUI library
nginx-common - small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
nginx-extras - nginx web/proxy server (extended version)
libksieveui4 - Sieve, the mail filtering language, GUI library
spamc - Client for SpamAssassin spam filtering daemon
libclamav6 - anti-virus utility for Unix - library
xmail - advanced, fast and reliable ESMTP/POP3 mail server
mail-stack-delivery - mail server delivery agent stack provided by Ubuntu server team
amispammer - Powerful Mail Server checker on blacklists
courier-base - Courier mail server - base system
courier-doc - Courier mail server - additional documentation
courier-faxmail - Courier mail server - Fax<->mail gateway
courier-imap - Courier mail server - IMAP server
courier-imap-ssl - Courier mail server - IMAP over SSL
courier-ldap - Courier mail server - LDAP support
courier-maildrop - Courier mail server - mail delivery agent
courier-mlm - Courier mail server - mailing list manager
courier-mta - Courier mail server - ESMTP daemon
courier-mta-ssl - Courier mail server - ESMTP over SSL
courier-pcp - Courier mail server - PCP server
courier-pop - Courier mail server - POP3 server
courier-pop-ssl - Courier mail server - POP3 over SSL
courier-ssl - Courier mail server - SSL/TLS Support
courier-webadmin - Courier mail server - web-based administration frontend
feed2imap - feed aggregator (RSS/Atom) which puts items on a IMAP mail server
libnet-server-mail-perl - versatile and extensible mail server framework
mailfront - mail server network protocol front-ends
mlmmj - mail server independent mailing list manager
prayer - standalone IMAP-based webmail server
sqwebmail - Courier mail server - webmail server
tumgreyspf - external policy checker for the postfix mail server
```

Looking at the description beside the package name, It seems `xmail`, `prayer` and `sqwebmail` could be the names I needed.

---

If you have `synaptic` package manager installed, you can also search in it by clicking the search button.

Here is a screenshot for doing it in synaptic

[image: synaptic search]

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the binary, you can search for it with `apt-file`.

If you want to know which package provides `/usr/bin/emacs`, use

```
apt-file search /usr/bin/emacs
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#line-103.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to follow the other answers, usually research is a good idea.

But you're just looking for ways to add basic functionalities like various servers (such as web, database, mail etc), different Desktop Environments `tasksel` can be a good option as well. `tasksel` let's you select tasks like "Mail server" and installs the necessary default packages for that task.

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel 
sudo tasksel
```

Check the screenshot for of a `tasksel` waiting for selection

[image: Tasksel screenshot]

Comment: Please add more details. It's unclear how tasksel will solve the problem

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted, I added details. Tasksel isn't a complex program :-)

Comment: I don't know how installing `tasksel` solves the problem. Shed light on that part of the question. Oh, I'm not the downvoter

Comment: Didn't expect you to come back on your own just to downvote.  :) The upvotes on your comment makes it clear others concur with you. I added a screenshot, if people still find it unclear, I'll have to suffer the downvotes, because tasksel is too simple to say more about it. :)

Comment: I have a suggestion. Include in your answer that, running `tasksel` will give you an option to install mail server. But still, `mail-server` was just an example from OP. `tasksel` doesn't provide many options other than some defaults

Comment: Thanks, I added it. I thought  as well that there wouldn't be many options, but I didn't check tasksel for ages. Did you see the screenshot, that is already so much more than I expected. Honestly, I think tasksel isn't a good solution, the other answers as stated in my answer are better, but it is what OP was asking for.

Comment: The screenshot will be better if it includes __Mail Server__  entry. But still better than the initial version

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user-friendly `apt-get` you should be using `apt`.
It also provides the `search` command which searches for package names and descriptions:

```
$ apt search "mail server"
$ apt search database GUI
```

Comment: How is it more "user-friendly" than `apt-get`? You need to type 4 less characters only.

Comment: @Anwar You also don’t need to remember which subcommands belong to `apt-get` and which to `apt-cache`, for example. However, I think this answer should be a comment to your answer instead of a standalone answer.

Comment: @Anwar Did you see the output of `apt` vs `apt-get`? Try to install something using `apt-get install` vs `apt install` and see the differences in the UI...

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, I used both

Comment: @Anwar didn't notice that `apt` output is coloured and provides a proper progress bar (for example)? `apt-get` does not do that.

Comment: @Bakuriu I've noticed all those. But those doesn't make difference in finding a package required using `apt-cache`. That was my point

Comment: @Anwar Do you mean except the fact that there is no `apt-get search` command?

Comment: @Bakuriu I meant `apt-cache`. Using `apt` here making no big difference than `apt-cache`.

Comment: @Anwar Except that `apt-cache` is a random name for such functionality. Think of a newbie user... why would he think he needs to use apt-**cache** ? The term *cache* does not make sense for a searching functionality. That's a difference in UX.

Comment: This is same as remembering the fact that `apt` has a search command. If a person can remember that, he/she can do this too. That is what people has been doing for decades.

Comment: @Anwar No, it's not the same thing. Once one knows `apt` by using `apt --help` he can know how to install/uninstall programs but **also** how to search them. So he has to remember one command: `apt`. Besides just by trial&error `apt search` is much easier to find then `apt-cache`. Moreover even if you know `apt-get` you still wont be able to know how to search a package because `apt-get --help` does not mention `apt-cache`.  Sure: once one knows how to do a thing it knows how to do a thing, independently of how hard it is (by definition). The point is: UX is about making it easier to do things